# Android SDK platform targets (for sbt gen-android <platform-target> <package-name> <name>)

Tags: android, select, sdk, sbt, platform

I'm at a loss about the platform-target parameter for the gen-android command (android-sdk-plugin for SBT). Google isn't very helpful, too. Looks like there must be a way of questioning android sdk about platform targets available (installed)?

No gen-android usage examples, too.

Answer (score 8):

Make sue you are running SBT 0.13.5 or greater.

Then run `sbt "gen-android android-19 com.your-pack testName"`.

This should create the packages and use android sdk version 19.

Comment: Thanks! If your android-* isn't quite right, the system suggests some choice. You still have to know how to put a wrong question...

Comment: Had the exact same question. Can't believe they can't be more specific about this.